# Convert Boolean text search into SQL Query WHERE Clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We're looking to implement a Search query that will do a full-text search on a specific column in SQL. We're open to do it in `SQL` directly or in `C#` as suggested by TomC below. The query will be entered by users like -

```
(A AND B) OR (C AND D)
```

We want to convert this search text into SQL query as below -

```
WHERE (col LIKE '%A%' AND col LIKE '%B%') OR (col LIKE '%C%' AND col LIKE '%D%')
```

Please advise what would be the best approach to handle this.

Comment: Whats the front end? I suspect the query is going to be constructed there. Probably going to be much easier than string manipulation on a free text field in sql. Also more secure to avoid any sort of sql injection attack. Or is it always 4 values as you have said?

Comment: The front end is ASP.Net written using C#. You gave a nice idea to construct the query in C# itself. It can definitely be more than 4 values :)

Comment: Is it only two arguments with `AND` and groups separated with `OR`? Or  you can have many arguments with `AND` and nested groups, too? If you want to support nesting you need a parser, if you have a pattern it will be more easier.

Comment: We can have multiple arguments, not really nested groups. we will maximum have 4-5 groups separated with AND / OR / NOT / "" and at times we may have brackets just like A OR B or may be C AND D

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is the best regex replace, but it works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication58
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern = @"(?'prefix'[^\w]+)?(?'var1'\w+)(?'operator'\s+(AND|OR)\s+)(?'var2'\w+)(?'suffix'.*)?";
            string input = "(A AND B) OR (C AND D)";

            Match match = null;
            do
            {
                match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
                if (match.Success) input = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, ReplaceVars(match));
            } while (match.Success);


        }
        public static string ReplaceVars(Match m)

        {
            return m.Groups["prefix"] + "col LIKE %'" + m.Groups["var1"].Value + "'" + m.Groups["operator"] + "col LIKE %'" + m.Groups["var2"].Value + "'" + m.Groups["suffix"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the headsup, will try and let you know.

Comment: This kind of works. I modified the ReplaceVars() as 

return m.Groups["prefix"] + "col LIKE '%" + m.Groups["var1"].Value + "%'" + m.Groups["operator"] + "col LIKE '%" + m.Groups["var2"].Value + "%'" + m.Groups["suffix"];

However, it fails if the input string becomes as (A AND "B") OR (C AND D)

Comment: The double quote is not a word character (\w+).  So you can replace with : [\w"]+ which will include either a word character or the double quote character.

Answer (score 1):

On the database side, I would use [`CONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) if you are looking for fuzzy or less precise matches. I mention this in case you made the original post simplistic. Unlike `LIKE` with a leading wild card, it can use an `INDEX` which would make it faster. Using `LIKE` in this fashion would result in a table scan. You will have to create the [`FULLTEXT INDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to use `CONTAINS`.

Another approach would be to use `CHARINDEX`. This can use an index, but isn't guaranteed to. I'd test this compared to `LIKE` in your environment.

```
where 
      (charindex('A',col) > 0 and charindex('B',col) > 0) 
   or (charindex('C',col) > 0 and charindex('D',col) > 0)
```

Comment: CONTAINS looks like a good option and we're open to use anything that works. The problem is how to generate the query based on search conditions written