# Pass WHERE clause as parameter into a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on a stored procedure where one of the parameters used in `WHERE` clause needs to be sent from the code. For ex -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test
    @param1 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table 
    WHERE @param1
END
```

In the above stored procedure, the value passed to `@param1` would be something like `Col1 LIKE '%abc%' AND col1 LIKE '%xyz%'` I understand that this can be done using dynamic SQL, but I would prefer not to use this.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have a `varchar(MAX)` column and I am looking for searching this column based on values entered by the user. The operator used (AND / OR) is selected by the user on the front end. This is inline to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608427/convert-boolean-text-search-into-sql-query-where-clause)

Comment: If you have to do it that way then dynamic SQL is your only option. However thats not a good way to do it - leave you open to injection, and harms performance.

Comment: But don't. This is a terrible idea. You are creating implicit links between the 2 layers that only complicate your architecture.

Comment: That's one of the main reasons I don't want to use dynamic SQL. Any other options?

Comment: You'd need to explain what you are trying to accomplish in more detail in order to come up with a better approach.

Comment: @DaleBurrell added more info. Hope this helps

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Agreed, this is a sample to showcase here :)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a user defined table type with 3 columns:
- match type (equals, like etc)
- searched value
- and/or

I would pass this into my SP and then use dynamic SQL to build a query.

You don't really have many other options when allowing the user to define the search criteria. But I would definitely pass the search conditions in in a structured format so that you have ultimate control over the final SQL (as opposed to the app poking pre-formed SQL in).

Comment: I thought of using a User defined table type, but the query entered by the user is something like (A OR B) AND (C or D). This filter needs to be applied on the column. Using the table type, it will be tricky to generate this dynamic SQL. Also, this is the only field that is needing dynamic SQL. I have 50 other parameters passed to the procedure and converting all to dynamic SQL is a pain

Comment: You can use your existing search query into a temp table and then use the dynamic SQL for this final filter.

Comment: Its going to be dynamic SQL either way, its just how you pass the details into your SP - and I wouldn't want to be passing in SQL fragments.

Comment: Gotcha. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments there's usually never a good reason for passing in a complete clause:
- You're removing abstraction of the Database layer (if you need to switch DBMSs, you'll need to change the where clause syntax, assuming it's different).
- You might be opening yourself up to injection attacks.

Understand your requirement better and parameterize your stored procedure accordingly.
For example,
you need the following queries possible:

```
select * from TABLE where column1 like '%XX%' and column2 like '%YY%'
select * from TABLE where column1 like '%XX%' or column2 like '%YY%'`
```

pass 3 parameters `column1Value`, `column2Value`, `clauseConnector`

Then use conditionals to execute different queries:

```
IF @clauseConnector = 'AND'
  BEGIN
    select * from TABLE where c1 like '%' + @column1Value  + '%' AND c2 like '%' + @column2Value  + '%'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    select * from TABLE where c1 like '%' + @column1Value  + '%' OR c2 like '%' + @column2Value  + '%'
  END
```

You can also use dynamic sql to build your query in one statement.

```
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ' + 
'Column1 like ''%' + column1Value  + '%'' '
+ @clauseConnector  + ' ' +
IIF (@column2Value IS NOT NULL,'Column2 like ''%' + column2Value  + '%'''
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

Comment: If you see the linked question, you will understand that this approach is not going to work.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds simple enough based on your edit there's a varchar(MAX) column which you want to search.  Let's call that col1

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test
@param1
AS
BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM Table WHERE **col1** like @param1
END

Comment: This wouldn't work like that as we have multi columns values to be checked through.

Comment: The implementation is possible without a dynamic query but you will need carefully consider the consequences.  If you have one varchar(max) column called col1 and this column has a copy of the data from that row as a string then it’s possible to simplify you search criteria to “where col1 like @param”. This avoids dynamic queries but exposes other issues. If the size of the other fields are fixed add them up and use that instead of max. You could use a trigger update the col1 maybe with an XML row. Will work for less than 5,000 row. Otherwise use sp_executesql